# Can Not query SQL Server 2008 from Visual Studio 2013 Community second day of development using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2013

I am attempting to execute an SQL Server query with LINQ to SQL in Visual Studio. When I first create the project the connection works perfectly.  When I save and come back to work on the project the next day I can now longer retrieve any data from SQL Server.  I open the Server Explorer and test the connections are working still this error.  Any help is appreciated.

*A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)*

Here is a method of my class

```
    private string MyDUIDSql(string pSPID)
    {
            PATH1PRDDataContext path1prd = new PATH1PRDDataContext();
            var query = from sampleunits in path1prd.TBLSAMPLEUNITs
                        where sampleunits.PROJECTSUID == pSPID && sampleunits.AssignmentTypeID < 19
                        select sampleunits.DUID;
            return query.Single();

    }


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<configuration> 
    <configSections> 
    </configSections> 
    <connectionStrings> 
        <add name="WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings.PATH1PRDConnectionString" 
            connectionString="Data Source=PATHSQL;Initial Catalog=PATH1PRD;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=********;Password=******"  

            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 
        <add name="WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings.PATHBaseline_BESConnectionString" 
            connectionString="Data Source=PATHSQL;Initial Catalog=PATHBaseline_BES;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=******;Password=************"

            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 
    </connectionStrings> 
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" /> 
    </startup> 
</configuration>
```

Comment: No code, no answer. We are not foretellers.

Comment: Show also connection string from config file.

Comment: Console.WriteLine(path2prd.Connection.State); returns Closed and path2prd.Connection.Open(); throws an error

Comment: This can be anything from poor lan to some firewall settings, sql server setttings, domain permissions etc etc. This answer can't be answered.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is simply that the it can't open the SQL Server connection. Data Source is the server/instance of SQL Server.  This is usually and IP address, or set to "." meaning my local instance.

Assuming PATHSQL is an alias that points to a SQL Server Instance.

Open Start > All Programs  > Microsoft SQL Server > Configuration Tools > Sql Server Configuration Manager.  Check the SQL Native Client Configuration > Aliases section.  It should have one for "PATHSQL" - What server does that point to?  If there isn't one you need to create one that points to the server where SQL server is installed.

Alternatively just set the DataSource value to "." for your local machine or the ip of the database you wish to connect to.